# Does a Neighborhood System exists, sucht that all its elements are open sets

Tags: general-topology

My Question ist the following:
Given a Topological Space, is it always possible to find a Neighborhood System (of a point x) such that all its elements are open set?

My Thought Process:

Definition 1 Neighborhood
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $x \in X$.
A Subset $N$ is called Neighborhood for $x$, if there exists a open Set U such that
$x \in U \subseteq N$.
Let $\mathcal{U}(x)$ be the set of all Neighborhoods of x.

Definition 2 Neighborhood System
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $x \in X$. A System $\mathcal{B}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{U}(x)$ is called Neighborhood System in x, if for every $U \in \mathcal{U}(x)$ there exists a $V \in \mathcal{B}(x)$ such that $V \subseteq U$.

Further I know that for
$$U \in \mathcal{U}(x) \Leftrightarrow x \in \operatorname{Int}(U)$$
Where Int( ) stands for the interior of a Set.

If one now defines $\mathcal{B}(x)$ as
$\mathcal{B}(x):=\{\operatorname{Int}(N):N \in \mathcal{U}\}$

This means that for every point $x \in X$, one can define a neighborhood System only containing open sets. I am quite new to topology, and would like to now if my assumption is correct or if there is somewhere a mistake.

Comment: Easier: $\mathcal{U}(x)\cap\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, for every "neighborhood system" for $x$ (a more common name is a "base for the neighbourhood filter") there is one that consists of open sets only and taking the interiors is a logical and correct way to do that.